# Set of alternate TextViews and ExpandableListView inside a RelativeLayout are not scrollable when they take extra screen space

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout, expandablelistview

I have three sets of TextView as a heading and ExpandableListView as content inside a RelativeLayout, that is I have 3 TextViews and 3 ExpandableListViews alternating between each other. Now in devices with smaller screen size, my layouts go out of the view below the screen. So logically the user would try to scroll down. But its not scrolling the way it should[image]

As shown in the picture above Men, Women, and Kids are TextViews and they have their respective ExpandableListViews each. I also have a list view above for Home and Settings. As seen in the picture most of Kids content is below the screen. But when I try to scroll its having none of it.

Here is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccc">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#cccc"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Men"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/listView"
        android:id="@+id/menTextView"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/menExpandableListView"
        android:layout_below="@id/menTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="women"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/menExpandableListView"
        android:id="@+id/womenTextView"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/womenExpandableListView"
        android:layout_below="@id/womenTextView" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kids"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/womenExpandableListView"
        android:id="@+id/kidsTextView"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/kidsExpandableListView"
        android:layout_below="@id/kidsTextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

This is how I solved it, I just had one Expandable List view and made the other TextViews are Group Headers inside Expandable List View without any children.

As suggested by one of the answers, I had a property that says if my Group is a header, so isHeader() gives if my group is a header or not.

Here is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="15"
    android:background="#cccc">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#cccc"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/listView"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my updated getGroupView in the Adapter for expandableListView that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ProductHeadGroup headGroup = getGroup(groupPosition);
    String header = headGroup.getGroupName();
    if (headGroup.isHeader()) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_main_header, null);
        TextView headerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idExpandableHeaderItem);
        headerTextView.setText(header);
    } else {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_header, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandableHeaderIcon);
        if (isExpanded){
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_collapse_dark);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_expand_dark);
        }
        TextView headerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idExpandableHeaderItem);
        headerTextView.setText(header);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

As shown above, I implemented my custom expand/collapse indicators having my own ImageView in the GroupLayout. and disabled it in my Activity using

```
expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null)
```

Comment: Do you expect your whole `RelativeLayout` to scroll? Or only the 3rd `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: try adding ScrollView as parent Layout

Comment: @ArchitJain did try adding a scrollView, but that didn't work.

Comment: @user3249477   I want the whole relative layout to scroll, not just the ExpandableListView. Like When I expand one of the groups, some part of the relative layout goes out of the screen, so when I scroll up or down it should scroll with the group staying expanded.. Or something reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem is in your design. First of all RelativeLayout takes up the whole screen (or the free space that's left) thus, the last ExpandableListView becomes very small and practically unscrollable.

To do this **right**, you should:

- **Make a single ExpandableListView**
- **Headers act as empty groups**

  - Custom type

    - `getGroupTypeCount` return 2 (*header* and *non-header*)
    - `getGroupType` return 1 if a header, else return 0
  - Custom layout

    - Determine the group type in `getGroupView` and inflate accordingly
    - No indicators
- **Custom group indicators**

  - Disable default indicators (`expListView.setIndicator(null);`)
  - Make them a part of your normal group layout (as an ImageView)
  - Set (expanded/collapsed) image at `getGroupView` and `elv.setOnGroupItemClick()`
  - [Default drawables](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) (action bar icons -> *ic_action_expand.png* and *ic_action_collapse.png*)

---

Looks like a lot of work but in the end it will be worth it.

The result: a dynamic ExpandableListview which scrolls properly no matter how many headers, groups and children you have.

*Side note:* I'd recommend a *CursorTreeAdapter* for applying, *CursorLoader* for fetching and *SQLite* for storing the data.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I waited so long for someone to answer, and totally disappeared when someone finally replied..

Comment: This is how I did it, and used the isExpanded flag available to us in getGroupView to have my custom expand/collapse indicator instead of messing with elv.OnGroupItemClickListener

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` is not scrollable, hence cannot be larger than the physical display.

The first solution that comes to mind is placing `RelativeLayout` in `ScrollView`. There are couple of issues with that:

- You need to set `RelativeLayout` height to `wrap_content` when placed inside `ScrollView`.  If `ExpandableListView` height is set as `wrap_content` then it's parent height cannot be `wrap_content`. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html):

> Note: You cannot use the value wrap_content for the
>   android:layout_height attribute of a ExpandableListView in XML if the
>   parent's size is also not strictly specified (for example, if the
>   parent were ScrollView you could not specify wrap_content since it
>   also can be any length. However, you can use wrap_content if the
>   ExpandableListView parent has a specific size, such as 100 pixels.

- `ListView` should never be placed under `ScrollView`. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
>   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
>   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
>   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
>   ScrollView.

In this specific case, since the view hierarchy is flat (just one level), you should be using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. `RelativeLayout` will normally make 2 measure pass.

**Solution:**

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and set `layout_weight` for all the list views including expandable list view, so that left out space is equally divided by all the list views.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#cccc"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Men"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/menTextView" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/menExpandableListView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="women"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/womenTextView"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/womenExpandableListView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kids"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/kidsTextView"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/kidsExpandableListView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What will this look like on small screens? I believe all you will see are the TextViews.

Comment: @user3249477 I checked in Moto G in landscape mode, all 3 expandable list views are displayed with 1 item. Rest items need to be scrolled. Either OP has to change the UI design or have to live with it.

Comment: What you are describing, one item in each expandable list view, I also got that result after fiddling with it for a while.. But that is not acceptable. How do you suggest I change my UI where I have three levels, Men -> Footwear -> Casual Shoes etc..

Comment: your solution looks good in larger screens but still looks a tiny bit awkward in small screens, I want all the children and opened groups to be opened completely, and not fit in the little space they are given wrt to the ratios I set up. I want them to wrap content and still be able to scroll to the missing view. I'm gonna try the other answer as well before marking the correct answer. Your solution is still acceptable but I want to test the other solution too.. and see what works better..